# Filling files from a named list with multiple lines of text

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a large number of files from a list of filenames

The contents can be identical in each file, but that contents requires two rows

The problem I'm having is that the form of `ECHO` I'm using is just printing `\n` as plaintext.

My content requires a lot of `|`'s so this is why I'm struggling

```
ECHO ON

SET FileList==P:\createfile\list.txt
SET CreateFileDir=P:\createfile

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN (%FileList%) DO (

    ECHO D^|1^|5000026789^|\n1^|23>"%CreateFileDir%\%%~F.txt"

)
GOTO EOF
```

The `\n` here does nothing. I have tried a second line of ECHO, but it only prints the second line.

I have also tried every possible way of printing `\n` but with no results. I've also done `ECHO -e` and `ECHO $'..'`

This is what the end result should look like:

```
D|1|5000026789|
1|23
```

Comment: What do you want your final files content to look like? Please [Edit] your question, to submit that content formatted as code.

Comment: `\n` has no special meaning to `cmd` - it's just another literal. You need 2 separate `echo` statements; one terminating with the `pipe befor `\n` and another starting with the `1` following `\n`.

Comment: @Magoo I've tried, but it only seems to create a file with one line, which is the second echo. So if this is the case, I'm still not sure how to resolve

Comment: You have not shown us the way you are creating the file. You need `(echo...` for the first `echo` and `echo....)>filename` for the second, OR `echo...>filename` for the first and `echo...>>filename` for the second, assuming that you want the file to be created by the first and appended by the second. OR you could use `del filename 2>nul` before the `for` and `echo...>>filename` for both `echo`es.

Comment: Like this: ```(ECHO D^|1^|5000026789^|& ECHO 1^|23) 1>"%CreateFileDir%\%%~F.txt"```

Comment: @Compo this is right, do you want to post as an answer so I can accept it?